# How to get auto-width on a CSS grid container with auto-fit columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a CSS grid with a dynamic number of columns based on the available space, implemented like this:

```
.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 8em);
}
```

As I'm using `auto-fit`, implicit grid columns are added as I add items to it, capped by the amount of horizontal space available to the grid container.

Now, in some cases I don't want to give the grid container a specific width, because I don't know how many items will be in it. Instead, I would like its width to be based on its contents, i.e. the number of actual rendered columns. (This will allow me to place it e.g. in a `<dialog>` so that the dialog's width is determined by the grid's contents.)

So, as an example, if there's only one column, I would expect the grid to be 8em wide, whereas if there's 3 columns, I would expect it to be 24em wide.

Is there any way to achieve this, without calculating an appropriate size in javascript?

Comment: `display: inline-grid; grid-auto-flow: column; grid-auto-columns: 8em` ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif — OMG, chef kiss. Question: this is actually an "explicit" grid, right?

Comment: @ralph.m it's an implicit one because we are not defining columns, they get created as needed, we are only defining the flow algorithm.

Comment: Okay, thanks. The browser grid inspector was making them look like explicit ones.

Comment: Ahh, using auto-columns instead of template-columns with repeat(auto-fit) – I hadn't thought of that! However, I'm not sure if I can achieve the capping of the number of columns to fit the available space, like I get with repeat(auto-fit).

Answer (score 0):

You might have more luck doing this with Flexbox.

```css
article {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  background: #e7e7e7;
}

div {
  flex: 0 1 8em;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div>This is some content</div>
  <div>This is some content</div>
  <div>This is some content</div>
  <div>This is some content</div>
</article>
```

Those divs will wrap once they run out of space.

Comment: Yup, already did that. There are a couple of downsides to it, but it's good enough. Just wanted to check if there was a grid based solution I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your goal you can achieve this with the following:

```
.my-grid {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 8em);
  max-width: -webkit-fill-available;
}
.my-grid__item {
  inline-size: 100%;
}
```

display: inline-grid and -webkit-fill-available will cause the grid container to always scale to the width of the items, while the grid-auto-flow will force the grid to place content in columns without wrapping. However please note that you need inline-size: 100% or width:100% on the grid items for it to work.
This way you can have a responsive grid scaling itself to the number of columns populated with content.